# preview schema of resulting table

Tags: mysql

I'm building a db interface for MySQL. Say there is table A and table B. I'd like to know table's (A join B) resulting schema without performing an actual join operation(which could be time consuming in some cases). Is that possible in SQL?

Comment: You could issue a `DESCRIBE tbl` on the both tables to get their schema. Or query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database directly.

Comment: So I'd have to 'join' the two schemas server-side with PHP for example. I was hoping I could get that done in MySQL. Maybe some kind of dummy table(with no data, just the schema) would help.

Comment: Besides executing the query, using magic might help...How could you possibly know the result of a query without executing the query? Or I may have misunderstood your question...

Comment: Say I have A(ID,name,surname,code1), B(ID,code2). Then the join operation would go like this C(ID,name,surname,code1,code2). I wish to know C's schema without having to actually match tuples in a join operation.